# How to connect a two bubble in bubble chart?

Tags: css, reactjs, d3.js, highcharts, sass

I need to plot a chart which should look like [image]. Though this is a complicated form of a bubble chart(I might be wrong ) how to achieve this as all the bubble chart I have checked out have independent bubbles. What is the better solution to achieve the above chart ?. The data  inside each bubble is going to be added dynamically . 
Any suggestion here will be appreciated as I have run out of ideas.

P.S :Please let me know if this can be achieved though D3.js or css

Comment: It seems like a mix of a networkgraph and packedbubble series. https://www.highcharts.com/demo/packed-bubble-split and https://www.highcharts.com/demo/network-graph but it is not available from regular API options. Requires a lot of core changes and seems like a custom project. In case of custom Highcharts project I can recommend to contact blacklabel company. https://www.blacklabel.pl/index.html